# Multiple Classes With Same Methods

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have many classes in a project that need to all have a base set of the same constructors and 1 public method. Below is an example of this partial class:

```
public partial class SHIPMENT_LINE
{
     private OracleConnection _rp = null;
     private EntityConnection _rpe = null;
     private static string _schema = "";

     public SHIPMENT_LINE() { }

     public SHIPMENT_LINE(BHLibrary.Configuration.ConnectionOption Environment)
     {
         SetConnection(Environment);
     }

     public void SetConnection(BHLibrary.Configuration.ConnectionOption Environment)
     {
         this._rp = Configuration.RPConnection(Environment);
         this._rpe = Configuration.RPEntityConnection(Environment, out _schema);
     }
}
```

I need to implement the same private variables, constructors, and the `SetConnection` method on each of my classes that I create. After this all exists in each class, then each class will do something different, so the classes are not all necessarily related, aside from the fact that they all have this same "Beginning."

How should I go about building each of these classes so that I do not have to implement this `SetConnection` method in each of the classes that I create?

Keep this in mind:

- Due to other restrictions, I cannot inherit from another class in any of these classes. I **can**, however, use Interfaces if necessary.

Comment: Seems you answered your own question, what's the problem is simply implementing an interface?

Comment: interfaces can't be used to dictate private variables. inheriting is exactly what you are looking to do in this case.  I don't know why it would be restricted.  It's also confusing as to why you would care about private variables.

Comment: @stephenbayer I actually never realized that, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest going for composition rather than inheritance...

Make each of the class implement an interface, then have another class (not related to these) which also implements the interface and has a concrete implementation of it. All the classes you've mentioned above should have an instance of this additional class and just call through to it.

Example

```
public partial class SHIPMENT_LINE : ISetConnection
{
   private ConnectionSetter connector = new ConnectionSetter();

   public void SetConnection(BHLibrary.Configuration.ConnectionOption Environment)
   {
      this.connector.SetConnection(Environment);
   }
}

public class ConnectionSetter : ISetConnection
{
    public void SetConnection(BHLibrary.Configuration.ConnectionOption Environment)
   {
      // Implementation
   }
}
```

Comment: I like where this is going, but one question about it:

Notice that the original `SetConnection` method in the Shipment_Line class is setting the private variables with the `this` keyword. If I create this `ConnectionSetter` class that implements the `ISetConnection` interface, how can I get the `SetConnection` method in the `ConnectionSetter` class to set the private variables in the `Shipment_Line` class?

Comment: @jaressloo: Firstly I'd suggest moving them to the ConnectionSetter if possible (that would be my preference in an attempt to separate concerns - why should a shipment line know how to handle a connection?). Understanding that sometimes you have these restrictions however you could add an additional interface that has the 'OracleConnection' on and pass 'this' into the ConnectionSetter constructor, then make the members internal or expose via a property and modify them when SetConnection is called.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't subclass then an abstract class is not a viable solution and interfaces are only going to give you the contract that your common classes conform to without any implementation.

I would suggest implementing the common functionality in a common class and using this as a private member in your other classes (I.E. composition rather than inheritance). Your other classes could all implement an interface to ensure they all have the same methods and they could just forward their calls onto the private classes implementation of the method.

E.G.

```
private MYClassWithCommonFunctionality xyz = new MYClassWithCommonFunctionality();
```

And then...

```
Private void MyCommonInterfaceMethod(object param)
{
    // Do derived class specific stuff here...
    xyz.MyCommonInterfaceMethod(param);
}
```

And as an added bonus and a bit of forward thinking....have the common class also share the same interface and pass an implementation of this into your other classes constructor. That way in the future you can swap the implementation for another.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot create a base class that will implement your common functionality (any reason why?) than you probably can use T4 template to generate partial class with your common methods.